# Why does a PHP object property throw a string conversion error in sql query when accessed directly?

Tags: php, json, oop, scope

Can anyone explain why the property of the $json object works in the database query when first assigned to a local variable, but throws a string conversion error if used directly?  Thanks!

```
<?php

    class Order {

        protected $json;

        public function __construct($json) {

            $this->json = $json;

        }

        public function createOrder() {

            $email = $this->json->email;

            //Works
            $sql = "INSERT INTO orders SET email='$email'";

            // Doesn't work -- Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string
            $sql = "INSERT INTO orders SET email='$this->json->email'";

            ...
        }

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

a) PHP's stdClass has no magic __toString() method, so there's no way for a stdClass to be used inside a string.
b) PHP's `"`-quoted string parser isn't greedy, so your

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders SET email='$this->json->email'";
```

is parsed/executed as the equivalent of:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders SET email='" . $this->json . "->email'";
```

which is where your error message is coming from. `$this->json` is an object, with no __toString() magic method, therefore the warning.

If you want to use a multi-dimensional object in a `"`-quoted string, you have to use the `{}`-extended string syntax:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders SET email='{$this->json->email}'";
                                      ^------------------^
```

which forces PHP to treat everything inside the `{}` as a single unit.

The same holds for arrays:

```
$foo[1][2] = 3;
echo "$foo[1][2]";
```

is executed as:

```
echo $foo[1] . "[2]";
```

and gives you

```
Array[2]
```

as the output - arrays in string context are the literal word "Array". Using `{}` makes it work as expected:

```
echo "{$foo[1][2]}";
```

outputs `3`.